# sqlcmd gives no sign of failure yet doesn't work

Tags: linux, azure-sql-database, sqlcmd

I am running sqlcmd from a linux bash script. My target server is an Azure SQL.  I execute an sql file with a lot of sql statements (around 2500). These are Insert/update/delete statements. I used the following command

```
sqlcmd -i $SQL_SCRIPT_FILE -m-1 -p
```

Initially there were individual sql statements in the file. When executing that, a lot of statements were being missed out (I found that by checking the database, as some of the insert statements does not reflect in db).

Then I put all the statements in try catch and transaction. I am writing the exceptions in an ErrorLog table. 
Now when I execute the file, nothing happen. I do not see any error in ErrorLog table, the sqlcmd output also not display anything specific. The output is:

```
(0 rows affected)
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
1 xact[s]:
Clock Time (ms.): total        23  avg   23.0 (43.5 xacts per sec.)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your transaction is rolling back (including any rows written to your `ErrorLog` table).  You haven't posted any `TSQL` source, so I'm not sure if you have the `TRY/CATCH` within a transaction or the transaction is within the `TRY/CATCH`.

I'd suggest following the guidance in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23057666) - (*TSQL Try / Catch within Transaction or vice versa?*).

> Only open a transaction once you are inside the TRY block and just
>   before the actual statement, and commit it straightaway. Do not wait
>   for your control to go to the end of the batch to commit your
>   transactions.
>
> If something goes wrong while you are in the TRY block and you have
>   opened a transaction, the control will jump to the CATCH block. Simply
>   rollback your transaction there and do other error handling as
>   required, which might include writing rows to your `ERRORLOG` table.

Here's the code sample from the post above.

```
BEGIN TRY

  BEGIN TRANSACTION SCHEDULEDELETE
    DELETE   -- delete commands full SQL cut out
    DELETE   -- delete commands full SQL cut out
    DELETE   -- delete commands full SQL cut out
 COMMIT TRANSACTION SCHEDULEDELETE
    PRINT 'X rows deleted. Operation Successful Tara.' --calculation cut out.
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH 
  IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
   BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION SCHEDULEDELETE
      PRINT 'Error detected, all changes reversed'
   END 
    SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
END CATCH
```

Comment: My scripts are exactly same. But nothing is being added to the error log table. The problem happen only when the script file is huge. I split out in multiple .sql files with try-catch and transaction and things are working well.